# nextjs - Does not getInitialProps working? in dynamic routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, next.js

i have a problem. Using getInitialProps function, the return value had not goes to parent component.

but, In getInitialProps function, I saw the right values in console.log

below the entity code

```
import * as React from "react";
import {dynamicPost} from "../../store/dynamicPost";
import AppLayout from "../../components/AppLayout";
import {toJS} from 'mobx';
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

const Post = ({post}) => {
  console.log("in Post, props ", post);    //  <<<<<<<<<<<   undefined. why?????
  const router = useRouter();
  const {id} = router.query;
  return (
    <AppLayout>
      <div>{id} article</div>
    </AppLayout>
  );
};

Post.getInitialProps = async ({res, query}) => {
  console.log("in Post, getIP, res  ;", res);
  console.log("in Post, getIP, query  ;", query);  // { id : 3 }
  await dynamicPost.eReactPostR(query.id);
  let post = await toJS(dynamicPost.eRPrender)
  console.log('in getinitialProps data;' , post);   // here, the value was that I want it
  return post;
};
export default Post;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getInitilProps` run in 2 different enviroments:

1. Server side, only on the first page render
2. Client side, when navigating using `Link` component from the first render.

Your implementation uses `dynamicPost` which may have different values when evaluated on the different envs

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but, I do not understand why I cannot have a value in Post component at 'props'. For solivng this problem, In the return value of getInitialProps has changed props to {props}. but I cannot solve this problem.